# Open other apps intents from my own?

Tags: android

I'm not yet an Android programmer but I have an idea which I would like to know is feasible or not.

Part of my idea requires that I can open different functions/intents of other apps from my own app. For example I would create an app that when pushing a button it will open a .gba file directly in the My Boy! emulator. If such an app doesn't support this, is there a way to pull it off by perhaps watching or debugging the intent that is open and recreating it somehow in my app?

Sorry if my question doesn't make sense, I'm still new to Android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most good apps that accomplish a particular task allow you to open files/URIs in them using Intents.

However, you should *never* directly launch an app using a full Intent. Instead, create an Intent using the URI to the file, and let Android create a chooser of all apps which can handle the Intent. If any app supports that file and is installed, and is willing to open it for you, it will show up in the list. If no such app is installed, you will get an `ActivityNotFoundException`, upon which you can request the user to install an appropriate app.

Comment: I see, thanks for this. So basically means if the app doesn't allow you to open it using the URI then I can't do it.

Comment: @user you *can* use a direct intent to the app's package name, but there is no guarantee that the app will respond as you want it to.